# REST API - Resources That Join Other Resources / Mapping Resources

Tags: rest

Assuming I want to stay close to REST principles, if I have a resource named `students` and a resource named `courses`, I could book someone on a course like this:

```
PUT: api/courses/{courseId}/students/{studentId}
```

Instinctively, I would like to list the student bookings like this:

```
GET: api/courses/{courseId}/students
```

But I would like to include some information relevant to the booking (like booking number), meaning a third mapped resource.

So, I'm proposing that to get the student bookings, we would need a separate booking resource, that might look like this:

```
GET: api/courses/{courseId}/student-bookings
```

My question: Does anyone see a problem with the above approach, since the endpoint I'm using to create the booking is different to the endpoint I use to retrieve the booking that has been created?

---

edit: Another alternative, which feels better to me would be the below, although it doesn't really change the question, which pertains to accessing a created resource using a different endpoint to the one that created it:

```
GET: api/courses/student-bookings?courseId={courseId}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming I want to stay close to REST principles [...]

REST doesn't care about the URI design. But using a URI that properly identifies your resources and allows your API to evolve is considered a *good practice*.

---

I understand the *booking* (or *enrollment*) as a *new resource* with it's own attributes.

So, besides `/api/courses` and `/api/students`, I would have `/api/enrollments`, that maps to the relationship between a course and a student.

An enrollment could be created with a [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) request, as shown below:

```
POST /api/enrollments HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "course": "designing-wep-apis",
  "student": "john.doe"
}
```

A successful request would return [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) and the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) of the enrollment that has been created:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /api/enrollments/20180012
```

The following request can be used to retrieve all enrollments of particular course:

```
GET /api/enrollments?course=designing-wep-apis HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

And the following to retrive all enrollments of particular student:

```
GET /api/enrollments?student=john.doe HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you see anything problematic with my original suggestion: `PUT: api/courses/{courseId}/students/{studentId}`

Comment: @Sparked I would only do it if a student requires a course to exist. Also keep in mind that `PUT` requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.